# I moved houses (40 miles), kept same internet service, but much, much slower service

Tags: wireless-networking, performance, isp

I recently moved about 40 miles to a new house.  I kept the same service provider, same plan, and same modem/router.  In my old house, the speed of the internet was a non-issue - click a page and you were there - so I never bothered to test broadband speed.

In my new house, despite the fact that my modem is better positioned in the home (it was in the basement, now on middle floor 10 feet away from where I am working), the internet speed is maybe half of what it was; maybe 25% or less.  I did a speed test, and I'm getting less than 1mbps upload and download.  There are noticeable delays even when going to sites like Google or Wikipedia.

I can call AT&T, but I can't even imagine the 'who shot John' BS there gonna spew at me.
I'm going to try debugging the various ways I know - but is it even plausible that my new geographical location (assuming all else is equal or better - which I am 99% sure is the case) - is the cause of the slowdown?  Is there a fix that won't cost me money?

Comment: If you are connected via ADSL.. the further you are from the phone exchange, the slower the speed will be. What service do you have? Cable? ADSL?

Comment: ADSL - and in my new house, I am closer to both the modem, and the external phone box.  Or is the phone exchange something else?

Comment: ADSL is affected on how far you are from the phone exchange. The phone exchange is that box that you can sometimes find on the corner of the street. So from those boxes to your house is what will affect ADSL speed mainly. The further you are from those phone exchange to your house, the slower it will get. http://www.dslreports.com/coinfo may help to find where is the nearest DSLAM exchange.

Comment: gotcha - how far is too far?  Do you know?

Comment: Sorry I don't know that one. But if it is too far, you won't get any signal (ie no internet, and the ISP should not be able to sell you any service). But since they can still offer the service, then it is still within certain distance from their DSLAM. But you may be further away in comparison to your old place.

Comment: DSL is distance sensitive with the maximum distance traditionally being 18,000 feet. You should be able to call your provider and ask them how far you are from their CO or exchange.